# How to login only once when using apscheduler?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I'd like to check the new posts every set time (using apscheduler) on the site where needs to be logged in and receive messages from telegram bot.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import telegram
import sys
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def scraping():
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

    LOGIN_URL = 'Login page url'
    LOGIN_DATA = {
    "user_id":"id",
    "password":"pw",
    "keep_signed":"Y"
    }

    with requests.Session() as s:
        login_req = s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=LOGIN_DATA, headers=headers)

        url = "address"
        req = s.get(url, headers=headers) 
        html = req.text      
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')           
        title = soup.select('#css values') 
        latest_title = title[0].text 

        token =  "certain value"
        bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)
        chat_id = 'id'

    with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'latest.txt'), 'r+') as f_read:
        before = f_read.readline()
        if before != latest_title:
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text= latest_title)
        f_read.close()

    with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'latest.txt'), 'w+') as f_write:
        f_write.write(latest_title)
        f_write.close()

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()        
scheduler.add_job(scraping, 'interval', seconds=30) 

scheduler.start()
```

With this code, the login process is also included in every interval and it's inefficient.
How can I check the posts repeatedly but keep the session alive with only one login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar issue before, and solved it by storing the session as a pickled object in redis.

When you try to login, get the pickled session, unpickle, and then try to use it. If it is no longer a valid session (for example, they time out your login session on the api), then create a new session.

something along these lines might work:

```py
import pickle
import redis

redis_client = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

conn = None

def connect(self):
    if conn is None:
        conn = # your login code here

        redis_client.set(
            "connection", pickle.dumps(# your session here)
        )

connection = redis_client.get("connection")

conn = pickle.loads(connection) if connection else None

connect()

# make connection is not already connected.
timeout = time.time() + 60 * 3  # 3 mins from now
while True:
    try:
        connected = # code to check if you are connected.. for example get a url.
        if not connected:
             raise AssertionError()
                 break

        except (AssertionError, ConnectionResetError) as e:
             if time.time() <= timeout:
                 time.sleep(30)  # wait 30 sec before retrying
                 # recreate login
                 connect()
                 continue
             elif time.time() > timeout:
                 raise ValueError("Connection failed after timeout.")
             else:
                 raise e
```